# Playframework file upload to remote server

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am following the example at https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-fileupload-example  that talks about how to do file upload using custom body parser. The example has the method `handleFilePartAsFile` which creates a file sink to write to the disk. My requirement is slightly different and I want to send the multi part form data to another http sink. I know the REST end point where I want to do it and it is that http end point which can write to disk. But for my requirement I think I also need to create a http sink where I can send this. How do I tweak that code and what should I change the sink to to make it work?